# Android media player with HTTP Headers via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, http-headers, http-live-streaming

I am looking for an Android media player that supports custom HTTP headers for HLS streams opened via Intent. MX Player supports headers, but not for HLS, like

```
http://example.com/mystream|headerName=headerValue&headerName=headerValue
```